# How do I keep latest of three setter values

Tags: java, xpages

I am maintaining an XPages application.  There is a "ServiceCost" object which has a field named "BudgetCode" and this has a corresponding field in the database.  The problem I have is that the interface has three tabs each displaying the ServiceCost object values and its BudgetCode field and when I amend the BudgetCode field in the first tab the objects setter "SetBudgetCode" is called three times and over writes the new value with the old value from the second and third tab.  How do I keep the new value?  That is how do I keep the value the first call to the "setBudgetCode" setter creates?

Thank you

Here is the tab controller showing the three relevant tabs;

```
<xe:djTabContainer id="ContracttabbedPanel"
    title="container" style="width: 100%;" persist="true"
    tabPosition="top" doLayout="false"
      rendered="#{ServiceSpendController.initialstagecomplete}">
    <xe:djTabPane title="Baseline" id="tab_baseline">
         <xc:ContractBaseline></xc:ContractBaseline>
         </xe:djTabPane>
         <xe:djTabPane title="Planned" id="tab_planned">
         <xc:ContractPlanned></xc:ContractPlanned>
         </xe:djTabPane>
         <xe:djTabPane title="Actual" id="tab_actual">
         <xc:ContractActual></xc:ContractActual>
         </xe:djTabPane>
</xe:djTabContainer>
```

And here is the XPage code for the budgetCode field;

```
<xp:inputText id="editBudgetCode" value="#{rowData.budgetCode}"
     style="width:75.0px" required="true">
     <xp:this.attrs>
     <xp:attr name="triggeringhandlerid" value="btnsavehandlerid">
     </xp:attr>
     <xp:attr name="triggeringhandlerid" value="btnbaservicespendrecalculatehandler">
     </xp:attr>
     <xp:attr name="invalidstring" value="">
     </xp:attr>
     <xp:attr name="message"
        value="Baseline Tab - Budget Code. This field cannot be null">
     </xp:attr>
     <xp:attr name="friendlyname" value="Budget Code">
     </xp:attr>
     <xp:attr name="insertfieldid" value="dspService">
     </xp:attr>
     <xp:attr name="tab" value="Baseline">
     </xp:attr>
     </xp:this.attrs>
     <xp:this.converter>
     <xp:converter converterId="SimpleString">
     </xp:converter>
     </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Some code to help describe the problem, and a well formatted question would go a long way here

Comment: And if you change the field in the third tab, it works?

Comment: Sven - Yes you are correct that when the value is changed in the third tab the new value remains and in the first and second tab the value is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **onchange** event on *client side* to set new/changed value to all three fields. Then you will have the right value in document after submit no matter in which order fields are saved back to document.

**Update:**

Your edit field `<xp:inputText id="editBudgetCode"` is embedded three times in your XPage inside of embedded custom controls - each in a tab of djTabContainer. After rendering, they'll get an id like

- id="view:_id1:ContracttabbedPanel:tab_baseline:_id3:editBudgetCode"
- id="view:_id1:ContracttabbedPanel:tab_planned:_id4:editBudgetCode"
- id="view:_id1:ContracttabbedPanel:tab_actual:_id5:editBudgetCode"

We can get all three inputText elements on client side with `dojo.query("[id$=editBudgetCode]")` (= all elements with an id which ends with "editBudgetCode") and work with them.

Add the following code to the XPage or custom control which contains the djTabContainer:

```xml
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onClientLoad"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        dojo.query("[id$=editBudgetCode]").forEach(function(node) {
          dojo.connect(node, "onchange", function() { 
                var newValue = this.value; 
                dojo.query("[id$=editBudgetCode]").forEach(function(node) {
                    node.value = newValue;
                });
          });
        });]]>
    </xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

It sets an onchange event for every budgetCode field `<xp:inputText id="editBudgetCode"...`. When the onchange event gets executed the new/changed value gets saved to "newValue" and put in all three fields. This way all three fields are synchronized on client side. When page gets submitted then you can be sure that the last entered field value gets saved.

**Update 2:**

One step further: fields should only be synchronized if they bound to the *same* Java object.

Add an additional attribute "boundto" to your field "editBudgetCode"

```xml
<xp:attr
    name="boundto"
    value="#{javascript: rowData.hashCode()}">
</xp:attr>
```

and extend the onchange function:

```xml
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onClientLoad"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
        dojo.query("[id$=editBudgetCode]").forEach(function(node) {
          dojo.connect(node, "onchange", function() { 
                var newValue = this.value; 
                var boundto = dojo.attr(this, "boundto");
                dojo.query("[id$=editBudgetCode]").forEach(function(node) {
                    if (boundto === dojo.attr(node, "boundto")) {
                        node.value = newValue;
                    }
                });
          });
        });]]>
    </xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

`.hashCode()` is used to get a string which differs from Java object to Java object. Instead, you can use a getter for an ID or another unique value from your object.

Comment: Thanks Knut. I understand your suggestion for the onChange above however, the problem is that there are NOT three edit boxes. On investigating the application it appears there are ServiceCost object(s) and each ServiceCost object is rendered in each of the three tabs. The users want to be able to change budgetCode field in any of the three tabs and the change is updated in the other two tabs. I have found that the change to the budgetCode field works when the update occurs in the third tab because it is the last of the three to be processed upon saving the document

Comment: What kind of tab control do you use? With `xp:tabbedPanel`, issue doesn't appear because only one tab at a time is rendered. So, is it `xe:djTabContainer` from ExtLib or something else?

Comment: Yes.  I think it is EXTLib.  I say that because when I started maintaining the app I had to set up certain plugins and one of these was to do with ExtLib I think

Comment: Can you provide a shortened code example from XPages source tab with tab control and a ServiceCost object field?

Comment: Correction.  The tab controller is a djTabContainer.  I have added the tab controller and budgetCode field XPage code.  Thanks for your assistance with this so far.  First time I have worked on an XPages project

Comment: Knut.  Thank you.  This has me a stage further and almost there.  Your solution works perfectly when there is only one ServiceCost on the XPage.  I apologise because I have not mentioned that the Xpage where the tab controller resides is for a Contract (Contract.xsp) and a contract can have more than one ServiceCost object- and so if multiple ServiceCost objects exist on a Contract they all appear in each tab.  If there is more than one ServiceCost object a change to BudgetCode in one changes them all.

Comment: Ok, next challenge, still same approach :) - I updated my answer.

Comment: Knut.  Thank you for your patience and expertise.  It all apears to be working now.  Dojo queries were completely new to me (something else I am going to have to learn!!).  Before your last feedback I was trying to discover a way of instead of using ".forEach" in the Dojo query a way to amend it to "use Current" or "use target object".  But your amendment appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class Test {
    private String value;
    private String firstValue;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        if (firstValue == null) {
            firstValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You will keep the first set value in a second variable.

If you want to allow only one set (and avoid the next set), you can also use that:

```
public class Test {
    private String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        if (this.value == null) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, in this code, if the first set gives a null value, you should have a wrong value from the other set. But I think that, in your case, this should not happen.

Anyway, I think you've got a design problem. You'd better not have 3 fields mapped to the same value to avoid this kind of behaviour.
The solution I gave you are not really pretty. But it will give you a quick-fix for your design problem.

Comment: I don't think this would work. Once set, you would be unable to ever change it. I suspect a partial refresh (and possibly initial page load) would set it to a blank string instead of leaving it as null, from which you would not be able to change it.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers I agree. But, if it does not need to update its model anymore, my solution works. But as I said in my answer, I think he has a design problem. He'd better re-consider its design.

Comment: Thanks Ipratlong.  Yes I tried something like this using an array.  But trouble is adding new object fields causes many issues elsewhere in the application (the application is quite complicated and I didn't build it) so I can't add new fields to the object without causing many more issues to resolve.

Comment: Yes Ipratlong.  I don't like the design at all.  A former colleague created it then left without much in the way of documentation.  It is very complicated and not the way I would have done it.  I have even found procedures that are never used etc

Comment: @user2696089 I know this too :). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you have three editable fields bound to the same underlying field, all three provide "new values". One should be editable and the other two just Computed Fields

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Yes that would work but trouble is I am bound by what the users want and they want to be able to amend the field in any of the three tabs.  Maintaining this app is driving me round the bend

Comment: Then use a button to allow them to set the value programmatically via a dialog box, and use Computed Fields to display the value. Either that or you need some logic to set the loaded property so only one editable field is loaded at any time.

Comment: Alternatively, bind the controls to different viewScope variables. Use logic on your save to identify the priority, i.e. if the first has a value, use that, else the second, else the third

Comment: ViewScope variables!!!  That sounds like an option.  I will try that and get back to you.  Cheers